# Is it legal to pass a null program argument vector to execve()?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, exec, system-calls

Consider following C code (x86_64)

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    execve("/bin/ls", 0, 0);
}
```

I compiled as `gcc a.c` and executed; I got a `SIGABRT` with error

> ```
> A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.  
> Aborted
> ```

Next running on gdb, at first I also got a `SIGABRT`, however I did second run and it worked!

> ```
> Starting program: /bin/ls 
> [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
> Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
> ```

Why?

---

I tested for `/bin/sh` and found it always worked with *argv[] = NULL ...
Again I wrote some executable file (without any parameter needed) to test and found all them work.

So I guess only `/bin/sh` or other shells would work with *argv[] set to NULL, other files (like `/bin/ls`) fail or behave unexpectedly.

Comment: read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Read https://linux.die.net/man/2/execve and see what parameters it expects.

Comment: Yeah I know it is UB and also what parametes execve() expects, but is there any way to figure out why it work, or just luck. 
I'm solving some security challenge and if I can find out why it works that could be a great improvement for my shellcode.

Comment: @poming What OS are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man page for the `execve()` system call says

> The `argv` and `envp` arrays **must** each include a null pointer at the end of the array.

If your program doesn't conform to those requirements, there's no certainty of how well things will go from that point on.  If it "works" for some programs, that's just bad luck.

---

The man page also says

> By convention, the first of these strings (i.e., `argv[0]`) should contain the filename associated with the file being executed.

That convention is rather strong (mandated by POSIX), so programs that fail to do so can be considered buggy.  It's probably a good idea for your `main()` to test it's been called correctly if you're going to rely on `argv[0]` so you can fail with a nice error message rather than a fault, but not all programs do.

Comment: The Linux man page documents the fact that *Linux* treats `argv=NULL` as a valid empty list, instead of returning `EFAULT`.  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#NOTES.  This is common in shellcode because it's already non-portable and it saves bytes.  And actual shells like /bin/sh do work if invoked with an empty argv (and thus argc=0).  [Why would this shellcode work if passes 0 as the environment pointer for execve?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70133251) The Linux man page recommends against it only for portability reasons; it is guaranteed to work on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Linux specifically treats `argv=NULL` or `envp=NULL` as a valid empty list, instead of returning -EFAULT<sup>1</sup>.  This is documented in the man page:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#NOTES.

This is *not* guaranteed by POSIX; some other OSes work this way but some don't.

Note 1:  (Or if going through the libc wrapper, returning -1 and setting errno = EFAULT).

This is common in shellcode because it's already non-portable, and it saves machine-code bytes in the payload. (Or in what you have to construct as part of a ROP attack).  But otherwise it's a very bad idea.  The Linux man page strongly recommends against it only for portability reasons; it is actually guaranteed to work on Linux.  (The execve itself; the program being invoked may be unhappy to find `argc=0` and `argv[0] == NULL`, as well as an empty environment.)

---

Actual shells like `/bin/sh` *do* work if invoked this way, which is the other part of why it's viable for shellcode not to construct a `{"/bin/sh", NULL}` array of `char*` and pass a pointer to that.

As Toby explained, it's not totally surprising for `/bin/ls` to bail out in that case.  Even if you had used `execve("/bin/sh", (char*[]){NULL}, (char*[]){NULL});` to use execve portably, you'd still be starting the program with `argc=0` exactly the way you are under Linux.

**TL:DR: don't do it unless it's part of some code-size or other hacky reason for not doing it the normal way.**