# Why would this shellcode work if it does NOT pass 0 as the environment pointer for execve?

Tags: linux, x86-64, system-calls, shellcode, execve

https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/46907

My understanding is that due to x64 calling convention, the 3rd paramfor execve, the envp, should be stored in rdx. But this shellcode doesn't zero this register, it only zero the rsi register (that stores arv). So that would cause a segfault if the current value of rdx doesn't point to a valid location, no ?

Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The asm *does* write RDX (with 0): note the [`cdq`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cwd:cdq:cqo) right before `syscall`**.  The sign bit of `EAX=59` is 0, so EDX = 0, and writing EDX zero-extends into RDX.

That's a [standard code-golf trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132981/tips-for-golfing-in-x86-x64-machine-code/147775#147775) for zeroing EDX/RDX with a 1-byte instruction instead of `xor edx,edx`, given a known non-negative EAX.

---

Linux special-cases NULL `argv` or `envp` pointers as working like an empty list (pointer to a NULL in memory).  See the man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#NOTES

The man page discourages the practice *for C programs* because it's not portable to other unixes, but shellcode already isn't, and it saves bytes of machine-code size.

In a `_start` in a static executable under Linux, all regs other than RSP will be `0`.  (This isn't guaranteed by the x86-64 SysV ABI, it's just the convenient value the kernel chooses to avoid info leaks before entering user-space.)  So it would have worked that way even if it did have the bug you thought.

But they also test by putting the machine code bytes into an array in `.data` in a C program, and calling it from `main()`.  **This would also happen to work with buggy shellcode that left RDX untouched**: compiler-generated code for calling via function-pointer would likely leave RDX unmodified.
On entry to main, EDI=argc, RSI=argv, RDX=envp.  So this block of machine code would start with RDX already being a valid pointer to `char **envp`!  Maybe a bit less of a test than they intended. :P

The 3rd arg to `main` being `envp` is not specified by POSIX but is widely supported: [Is char *envp[] as a third argument to main() portable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321435/is-char-envp-as-a-third-argument-to-main-portable)
x86-64 Linux's system-calling convention is quite similar to its function-calling convention, intentionally so that system-call wrapper functions only need `mov r10, rcx` / `mov eax, __NR_...` / `syscall`.

---

And BTW, **bad args to a syscall never result in a segmentation fault** (SIGSEGV signal being delivered to your process).  Instead, Linux system calls return a `-EFAULT` error code when you pass a pointer to unmapped memory, in a case where that's not OK.

(Fun fact: `write(1, buf, way_past_end)` will successfully write up to the end of the pages actually mapped starting at the `buf` address, and return that length.  You only get `-EFAULT` if 0 bytes were written to the fd before encountering on in an unreadable page.)

Comment: Thanks, so that would explain why the autor zero argv, so the spawned shell wouldn't immediatly exit with a bad value, but doesn't care about envp since it doesn't cause a segv in the original process and is also unlikely to affect the spawned shell (unless for some reason rsi happens to point to valid env variables) ?

Comment: Actually I edited the question title, I forgot the "not" but the answer is right.

Comment: @AaaBbb:  Oh, I see, I skimmed too quickly and missed what you were actually asking.  Maybe they got lucky with RDX in their test case and RDX happened to be NULL or pointing at some zeroed memory.  That was actually my edit that made the question title wrong; you wrote "if it doesn't set ..." which seemed ambiguous, sorry about that!

Comment: @AaaBbb: After actually reading the question properly, and looking at the linked code, I edited my answer to actually explain what's going on.  You missed the `cdq` instruction.